# Access Service inside controller

Tags: angularjs

Declared a Service

```
calculator_app.service('FullPath', function () {
    this.full_path = function (pt, pg, prt, cd,scpe) {

-- some logic---
};});
```

Declared the Controller

```
calculator_app.controller("Opportunity_Controller", ['$scope', '$http', 'ngDialog', 'FullPath', 'FillOpportunity', function ($scope, FullPath, FillOpportunity, $http, ngDialog) {

        $scope.find_path = function () {
            $scope.result_path = FullPath.full_path($scope.res_pt, $scope.res_pg, $scope.res_prt, $scope.res_cd, $scope);
}]);
```

The line FullPath.full_path is throwing error as FullPath is undefined....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies order should be same, the way you have injected in DI array, basically you had mismatch in injection of dependency sequence.

```
calculator_app.controller("Opportunity_Controller", ['$scope', '$http', 'ngDialog', 'FullPath', 'FillOpportunity', 
    //corrected sequence of dependencies below
    function ($scope, $http, ngDialog, FullPath, FillOpportunity) {
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves. However, I am not able to access ngDialog. ngDialog is undefined wen I did console.log                                                                    $scope.calculate_opportunity = function (ngDialog) {
    
     ngDialog.open({ template: '<div><h1>I am Ng Dialog</h1></div>' });
    }
    
    }]);

Comment: I thik you Havent change the code thoroughly as suggested in answer